# Doctrine2 query with select on multiple entities from different Symfony2 bundles

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello I have three Doctrine2 entities in my Symfony2 application: two ("Promo" and "PromoPeriod") in the bundle Acme:PromoBundle; one ("Shop") in the bundle Acme:ShopBundle.
The relationships are:
Promo - PromoPeriod: *Many-to-One*.
PromoPeriod - Shop: *One-to-Many*.

In the repository of the entity "Promo", I try to get all the promo and shops as follows:

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT p, s
            FROM AcmePromoBundle:Promo p JOIN p.period pp JOIN pp.shops s")
            ->getResult();
```

where: p.period is the relationship between the Promo instance p and the PromoPeriod period; pp.shops is the relationship between the PromoPeriod pp and the Shops.
The following error is returned:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("The parent object of entity result with alias 's' was not found. 
The parent alias is 'pp'.")
```

So, I argued that Doctrine is not capable of understanding the type of "s" (which is a Shop entity), since it is located in another bundle. Hence I tried to add an INSTANCE OF clause:

```
SELECT p, s
FROM AcmePromoBundle:Promo p JOIN p.period pp JOIN pp.shops s
WHERE s INSTANCE OF AcmeShopBundle:Shop
```

And again nothing. Perhaps this is not the way to solve the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: How should I use the FQCN? Remember that in Doctrine2 SQL query are formulated in a different way, since Doctrine2 is an ORM.

Comment: Mmm, mmm, FQCN = Fully Qualified Class Name, the way you select Entity is using a Doctrine2 alias (the AcmePromoBundle). The alias is used to shortcut the Entity name while writing a query, it is directly mapped to the actual namespace. I asked you to try to use the FQCN to check if it was an aliasing problem. Selecting FQCN should work in any part of your application.

Comment: The point is that I don't understand how to do that! Please, provide an example.

Comment: Instead of using `AcmePromoBundle:Promo` use `Acme\PromoBundle\Promo`

Comment: It doesn't work. The following error is returned: `Error: Class 'Acme\PromoBundle\Promo' is not defined.")`

Comment: It was just an example, make your your are using the correct FQCN...

Comment: An update! If I try to select only entity `p`, the query obviously works. If I try to select only `s`, the following message is returned: `Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.`.

Comment: I found on the official Docs that one can specify a query like in the following: `"SELECT p, s FROM AcmePromoBundle:Promo p JOIN p.period pp JOIN pp.shops s1, AcmeShopBundle:Shop s WHERE s1=s"` but this will return also rows with only a Promo entity or a Shop entity! I'm confused!

Answer (score 24):

You should select the 3 entities, like so

```
SELECT p, pp, s
FROM AcmePromoBundle:Promo p
JOIN p.period pp
JOIN pp.shops s
```

You're doing a fetch join, ie: doctrine will return the entities of the root of the query (here Promo(s)), and hydrate it with the additional select entities.
So if you tell doctrine to load the shops, that "come" from period, but to not select the period ... he can't do what you're asking it to do.
Here, the SQL query goes fine, it's when doctrine tries to hydrate objects that it throws an exception.

Read the related documentation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: Well, you are right, no error is returned! However, only the `p` objects are returned, notwithstanding that also `pp` and `s` objects are selected! It doesn't seem to be normal!

Comment: but pp and s are now available through p